# shallowMount : TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoint' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, nuxt.js

#### Version

1.0.0-beta.25

#### Reproduction link

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xrrjpy349

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Copy sample code setup from `https://codesandbox.io/s/8xrrjpy349`
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm run test` test execution will start and it will throw an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoint' of undefined`

#### What is expected?

Test should run without error as given in documents `https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/shallowMount.html`

#### What is actually happening?

Returning TypeError

---

1. project is setup using nuxt and vuetify.js
2. Added package.json in code setup with will give competed jest and vue-test-utils configuration information
3. Only bare minimum files are added to code sample

Comment: The issue must be with your :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp". You are using that with v-bind but we can't see where $vuetify is defined. How is it handled in nuxt.config.js?